# Handle Global Errors (OutofMemory, StackOverflow, etc) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

My application is designed to run 24/7 on a wide array of computers. That being said, what can go wrong will go wrong (Moore's Law), and therefore I'm looking to ensure my application is as stable as possible.

I was wondering if it's possible to handle global errors in VB.NET - such as OutofMemoryErrors, StackOverflow errors, and other misc. errors that can come up. While I know proper programming should stop these errors from occurring - there should always be a fallback.

With that being said, is there a way in Visual Basic .NET to handle errors like out of memory, stackoverflow, etc, and just have the application restart itself if it runs into one of these? Application.Restart()?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you mean [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)!

Comment: ... Once a process has run out of memory, you can't guarantee that it can do anything reliably, so if you do need something to restart your process, you will need a second process which monitors the first and restarts if necessary.

Comment: there is `My.Application.UnhandledException` but you cant do Application.Restart there.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write a service that communications periodically with the application, and when it gets no response it terminates and restarts the application. This should be possible if the service starts the application initially. This has the benefit of restarting when the application locks up without producing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your main app checks every n seconds for the existence on a known file - If the file exists - It deletes it.

Now create a 'Sentinel' app - It has one Job - to create a file that contains the time. This task will loop and every n seconds check the file exists. If the file does exist - Open the file and read the time. If the time read back is older than n seconds -  you main app has crashed - Delete the marker file and re-start the main app. If the file does not exist - your main app is still running.

Comment: You know, a mutex would be a much better way of doing this